# Unitary Mapping $U = \lambda I - T$ on $\mathcal H$ // Definition of Unitary

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

> $U$ is unitary mapping on a Hilbert Space $\mathcal H$, where $U = \lambda I - T$ and $T$ is compact operator. Show that $U$ can be diagonalized.

To start with, is the condition '$T$ is normal' or '$T$ is symmetric' not needed? It seems strange that those conditions do not exist in the diagonalization question.

Anyhow, I tried to show that $U$ is also compact. The reason is that under the condition that '$T$ is normal' or 'symmetric', $U$ is also normal and thus $U$ can be diagonalized. (the previous exercise was that if $T$ is normal and compact, then $T$ can be diagonalized). However, defining a bounded sequence $\{f_n\}_n$ s.t. $\{Tf_{n_k}\}_k$ converges doesn't seem to be enough to conclude that $Uf_{n_k}$ also converges to some function in $\mathcal H$...

Any rough ideas to start with this exercise would be grateful. Thank you in advance.

-this exercise is from Stein's Real Analysis Chapter4 Exercise 35-

---

Additionally, I've got a question about the term 'Unitary'

According to the Stein's textbook, 'Unitary mapping $U$' on $\mathcal H$ is defined as follows:

> 1. $U$ is linear
> 2. $U$ is bijective
> 3. $\Vert Uf \Vert_{\mathcal H} = \Vert f \Vert_{\mathcal H}$

However, I found another definition of 'Unitary Mapping' in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_operator): $U^{*}U = UU^{*} = I$. Using this definition, I figured out how to show the normality of $T$. But, I found it difficult to verify the same thing with the definition of Stein's book. I'd like to understand the relationship between the Stein's definition and the other one ($U^{*}U = UU^{*} = I$).

Comment: An automorphism of infinite dimensional normed vector space is never compact.

Comment: The compact operator $T=\lambda I-U$ is normal, hence diagonalisable, whence so is $U.$

Comment: Based on your comment, if $\{\phi_k\}_k$ is the eigenvectors of $T$ with eigenvalues $\{\lambda_k\}_k$, then $U$ has the same eigenvectors with the eigenvalues $\{\lambda - \lambda_k\}_k$. is this correct?

Comment: Yes this is what I meant.

Comment: Thank you. BTW, I got currious about the meaning of unitary mapping, written on the main question. It would be grateful to explain the difference, if you have some time.

Comment: The two definitions are equivalent

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thank you.